# mysql: Can I see an insufficient space aborted query in the slow query log

Tags: mysql

Does the slow query logs those that are aborted in the middles due to wait timeout ?

If not, where else I can see the queires that are aborted due to wait time out or those that are failed due to insufficient space.

Comment: I am not sure about disc space issue specifically, but the general query log, if activated and error log might have that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow queries must complete to be slow. Otherwise they're errors and logged accordingly.